# What's the difference between grep -r and -R

Tags: grep

In the man page:

> -r
>
> Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic
>   links only if they are on the command line.

what exactly does "being on the command line" means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Being on the command line" refers to the arguments passed to grep. If you give a symbolic link as an *argument* to `grep -r` it follows it. However, if `grep -r` encounters a symbolic link while *traversing* a directory it does not follow it (in contrast to `grep -R` which does).

Imagine you have a directory with a bunch of files in it, including one containing a symbolic link to `..` (the parent directory):

```
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 aw aw 47 Mar 31 16:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 aw aw 27 Mar 31 16:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 aw aw  0 Mar 31 16:05 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 aw aw  0 Mar 31 16:05 baz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 aw aw  2 Mar 31 16:04 foo -> ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 aw aw  0 Mar 31 16:05 quux
$
```

Then,

- `grep -r foobar .` will only grep the files inside this directory,
- `grep -r foobar foo` will grep the files in the parent directory (`..`) (following the symlink given as an argument),
- `grep -R foobar .` will also grep the files in the parent directory (following the symlink *not* given as an argument but found while traversing the current directory).

Answer (score 5):

If you check also `man grep`:

> **-r, --recursive**
>
> Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic
>   links only if they are on the command line.  This is equivalent to the
>   -d recurse option.
>
> **-R, --dereference-recursive**
>
> Read all files under each directory, recursively.  **Follow all
>   symbolic links, unlike -r.**

See an example:

We create in `/test` a file with the content

```
$ cat /test/a
Ping info
Hello
```

And then I create a symlink:

```
$ ln -s /test/a /test/dir/b
```

So that it looks like:

```
$ ls -l /test/dir
b -> ../a
```

And now we `grep`:

```
$ grep -r Ping /test/dir/*     #does NOT follow the symlink to ../a
a:Ping info

$ grep -R Ping /test/dir/*     #DOES follow the symlink to ../a
a:Ping info
dir/b:Ping info
```